# How can I formate String in java?

Tags: string

I have a file that contain information :

```
Cant Stop The Feeling!      Justin Timberlake 

One Dance                         Drake Featuring
```

like that separated by "\t"

my question is how I can take the first String which is here "One Dance " and put it in a String and take the Artist name "Drake Featuring "and put it in another using methods from String class .

Comment: May be do some regex?

Comment: @ Giorgi Nakeuri how?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aS5pU6/1

Comment: I want another way easy then that using the methods in class String :)

Comment: .split("\t") ... then take the first and last elements of the array and concat them.